# Guzzle async requests waiting for timeout even I use any to wrap around the promise - how can I make it return ASAP?

Tags: php, guzzle

My sample code is below, which basically tries to get a certain URL using a list of proxies. I want to return a result as soon as a proxy returns:

```
        $response = any(
            array_map(
                function (?string $proxy) use ($headers, $url) {
                    return $this->client->getAsync(
                        $url
                        , [
                            'timeout' => 5,
                            'http_errors' => FALSE,
                            'proxy' => $proxy,
                        ]
                    );
                }
                , self::PROXIES
            )
        )
            ->wait();
```

However, whatever the value I set in the timeout, I found out that the whole HTTP request only returns when the full timeout has passed, i.e. 5 seconds in this case. If I change 5 to 10, the whole HTTP request only returns after 10 seconds.

How can I really make it return ASAP?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the proxy/end server work well? I mean, Guzzle do nothing special with proxied request, so there are no settings that you can tweak.

What do you get after the timeout? Normal 200 response or an exception?

To me it looks like the issue is in proxy or in the end server. Have you tried to request the URL directly, without a proxy? Is it fast or still takes 5-10-... seconds?

Answer (score 0):

I finally wrote my own promise to solve the problem which really returns immediately.

```
        /** @var Promise $master_promise */
        $master_promise = new Promise(
            function () use ($url, &$master_promise) {
                $onFulfilled = static function (ResponseInterface $response) use ($master_promise) {
                    $master_promise->resolve($response);
                };
                $rejections = [];
                foreach (static::PROXIES as $proxy) {
                    $this->client->getAsync(
                        $url
                        , [
                            'timeout' => static::TIMEOUT,
                            'http_errors' => FALSE,
                            'proxy' => $proxy,
                        ]
                    )
                        ->then(
                            $onFulfilled
                            , static function (GuzzleException $exception)
                                use ($master_promise, &$rejections)
                            {
                                $rejections[] = $exception;
                                if (count($rejections) === count(static::PROXIES)) {
                                    $master_promise->reject(
                                        new AggregateException(
                                            'Calls by all proxies have failed.'
                                            , $rejections
                                        )
                                    );
                                }
                            }
                        );
                }
                while ($master_promise->getState() === PromiseInterface::PENDING) {
                    $this->handler->tick();
                }
            }
        );
        $response = $master_promise->wait();
```